# Does google's libphonenumber library get updated every time there is an update in a country as soon as possible?

Tags: java, android, shared-libraries, android-dialer

I am doing a project that I want to use libphonenumber library. I am thinking of a case study here:

Assuming I have a country short name GH (which is Ghana anyway) and the country code is +233. Lets say my mobile phone number operator prefix is 24 , then I can formulate a number like this +233 24 xxx xxxx .This number is valid according to the library. The problem here is that assuming my network operator decides to add another prefix say 55 because it now has more subscribers, Will the library be able to immediately validate a number like this +233 55 xxx xxxx as valid?.
Again, is the library very reliable when doing some programming?

Comment: Immediately - no, but your alternative is...

Comment: It's impossible for us to know this. Someone who has control over that list would have to update it. Whether that's an update to a Dialer app or some list on the cloud, we can't know

Comment: So it is not really recommended for a system that is been updated frequently?